# Raising error if string not in one or more lists

Tags: python, list, boolean

I wish to raise an error manually if a *target_string* does not occur in one or more lists of a list of lists.

```
if False in [False for lst in lst_of_lsts if target_string not in lst]:
    raise ValueError('One or more lists does not contain "%s"' % (target_string))
```

Surely there is a more Pythonic solution than the one specified above.

Comment: Example input, please?

Comment: How often are you doing the lookups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

```
if not all(target_string in lst for lst in lst_of_lsts):
    raise ValueError('One or more lists does not contain "%s"' % (target_string))
```

The generator yields `True` or `False` for each individual test and `all()` checks if all of them are true. Since we are using a generator, the evaluation is lazy, i.e. it stops when the first `False` is found without evaluating the full list.

Or if the double `in` on the same label seems confusing, one might

```
if not all((target_string in lst) for lst in lst_of_lsts):
    raise ValueError('One or more lists does not contain "%s"' % (target_string))
```

but I'm not so sure any more that actually increases readability.

Comment: Personally, I find your first solution more readable than the second. Either way, excellent answer!

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl Let me re-phrase that as "But you might find ... more readable, but that's up to personal taste" ;-)

Comment: 'target_string' is not defined inside if statement, thus the second line in both form raise a 'NameError'.
```NameError: name 'target_string' is not defined```

Comment: `target_string` is the name of the lookup variable in the question. It needs to be set before using the code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep lazy evaluation and enhance lisibility by :

```
for lst in lst_of_lsts :
   if target_string not in lst : 
      raise ValueError('At least one  list does not contain "%s"' % (target_string))
```